# CDbCommand returns wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm experiencing weird behavior from Yii. For some reason this code doesn't function as expected:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, class_id, lang FROM tbl_top_class WHERE class_name = :string";
$cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$data[':string'] = "sad";
$result = $cmd->queryAll($data);
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
$result2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
echo "<br>";
print_r($result2);
```

I would expect that `$result` and `$result2` are identical, but they are not. This is what the script outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [class_id] => 0 [lang] => en-us ) ) 
Array ( )
```

And here's the db structure & data:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_top_class`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_top_class` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lang` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `class_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `lang` (`lang`),
  KEY `class_name` (`class_name`),
  KEY `class_id` (`class_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_top_class`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_top_class` (`id`, `lang`, `class_name`, `class_id`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'en-us', 'discard', 0, 'Non-classifiable');
```

Both connections are to the exact same db and table, with exact same credentials. Why am I getting different results?

Comment: does anyone have any idea what's happening?

Comment: I encounter the same problem. But still finding what happen.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the original question WHY it works like that, but apparently this behavior can be circumvented by using the Yii query builder. Building the same query in pieces works as expected.

I'll mark this as the correct answer until someone can provide an explanation.